# Deleting / Recoloring a Line if it has been touched

Tags: arrays, pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to create a Support and Resistance indicator that creates lines when we make a new monthly level and then recolors them when the bar closes, then recolors again if we have hit the level and then delete if it is hit a second time. I have all of the parts working except some function to see if the level is "tapped". Here is my code so far:

```
support_break = close == m_s
resisti_break = close == m_r

var line [] LINEARRAY= array.new_line ()

if m_sr 
    line_sup = line.new (m_time, m_s, (m_time+1), m_s, xloc.bar_time, extend.right, color.white)
    line_res = line.new (m_time, m_r, (m_time+1), m_r, xloc.bar_time, extend.right, color.white)

    array.push (LINEARRAY, line_sup )
    array.push (LINEARRAY, line_res )
    
    if barstate.isrealtime                       //new
        line.set_color (line_sup, color.green)
        line.set_color (line_res, color.green)
    else if  (barstate.isrealtime == false)      //confirmed
        line.set_color (line_sup, color.purple)  
        line.set_color (line_res, color.purple)  
    else if (support_break)                      //tapped once
        line.set_color (line_sup, color.blue)
    else if (resisti_break)                      //tapped once
        line.set_color (line_res, color.blue)
    else if                                      //tapped twice and destroyed
        line.delete ()
```

So in all, I just don't have the "tapped once" or "tapped twice" function, any thought? Thanks so much!